# Finding a value between two integers in python

Tags: python, awk

I have the two following files.

1. If the second column of file 1 matches the first column of file 2
2. And if the second column of file 2 lies within the interval of 3rd and 4th column of file 1, print as in the output.

I was trying to write a python script for this but I don't know how to formulate it.

```
File 1:

a2 sca4 15 20
b3 sca4 22 30 
c4 sca6 45 65

File 2:

sca4 17
sca4 18
sca4 19
sca6 46

output:

a2 sca4 17 15 20
a2 sca4 18 15 20
a2 sca4 19 15 20
c4 sca6 46 45 65
```

Comment: Are the 2nd columns string unique in File 2 or do they repeat ? In your example `sca4` is present twice in file 1 but only once in file 2.

Comment: The second column in file 2, the numbers, they are unique. That is I can have several times sca4 but different numbers lying in the interval in file1. I edited my question. I am also trying but need to edit my code so to show what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a solution like Math already posted except with the `with` statement for file reading.

```
file2_dict = {}
with open("file2.txt") as fo:
    file_contents = fo.read()
    for line in file_contents.split("\n"):
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
        if key not in file2_dict:
            file2_dict[key] = []
        file2_dict[key].append(int(value))

output_string = ""
with open("file1.txt") as fo:
    file_contents = fo.read()
    for line in file_contents.split("\n"):
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        name, id, min, max = line.strip().split(" ")
        for value in file2_dict.get(id, []):
            if int(min) < value < int(max):
                output_string += line.replace(id, "%s %d" % (id, value))
                output_string += "\n"

print output_string
```

Comment: Not just to close the connection, but to me, with statement seems more 'pythonic' than file open and close :-)

Comment: Yes, this solution is great as I can understand it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import sys

def process_files(one, two):
    for line in [line.strip().split(" ") for line in open(two, 'r').readlines()]:
        for x in filter(lambda x: x[1] == line[0], [z.strip().split(" ") for z in open(one, 'r').readlines()]):
            if int(x[2]) <= int(line[1]) <= int(x[3]):
                print(" ".join(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_files(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Using `filter` and `lamda` is too advanced for me, would you mind explaining the code a bit please?

Comment: Basically, we take all the lines in "file B". For every line, we filter out the lines that don't match the first element from the set of lines in "file A".

After trimming down that set, we check if the lines in "file A" (after filtering), match the second condition (I.E., the 3rd and 4th column condition); if so, we print the matching line.

Comment: I am not trying to be a big head and all. If some topic seems to be advanced, it would be best to learn them. In case of Python, any topic can be learned quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `dict` to get every index available in file 2, and then go through file 1.

```
ff = file("file2", "r")
file2 = ff.readlines()
ff.close()
dict_f2 = dict()
for line in file2:
   ll = line.strip().split(" ")
   if (ll[0] in dict_f2):
       dict_f2[ll[0]].append(int(ll[1]))
   else:
       dict_f2[ll[0]] = list()
       dict_f2[ll[0]].append(int(ll[1]))

ff = open("file1", "r")
file1 = ff.readlines()
ff.close()
for line in file1:
    ll = line.strip().split(" ")
    if (ll[1] in dict_f2):
        sup = int(ll[4])
        inf = int(ll[3])
        for (comp in dict_f2[ll[1]]):
            if (comp >= inf and comp <= sup):
                print(line[0:2] + str(comp) + line[2:])
```